# How do I make a regex nginx location work?

Tags: regex, nginx

I have the following locations in my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location ~ ^/(?!api)(.*)/api {
        alias /var/www/api/$1;
    }

    location /api {
        alias /var/www/api/latest;
    }
```

I am trying to match /api as the latest version, and /<version>/api as anything else. The non regex location is working fine, but I am getting a 403 on the other location.

I don't think it is anything to do with the file and permissions that are being served, as I get a 403 if I try to access

```
/latest/api
```

even though these are the same files that are served by

```
/api
```

Does anyone have an ideas about why I am getting a 403?

The nginx error is:

```
directory index of "/var/www/api/latest" is forbidden, client:
172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "HEAD /latest/api/ HTTP/1.1",
host: "localhost"
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with nginx configs, but it seems that `/.+/api` (matches slash, one or more characters, slash, api) should do what you're looking for.

Comment: I looked into it some more and it seems, that you need to quote your regex expressions for the location.

Comment: Thanks. Not to say it can't be improved, but the regex is matching (as I can see from the nginx logs). It seems to be an nginx problem

Comment: Yes, I found that too, but quoting didn't make any difference!

Comment: What does `nginx -t` (test the configuration file) say?

Comment: It says it's all good

Comment: Actually I think I worked out what the problem was. When you give a regex for the location, it is not a *prefix*, it is the whole match, so I added the rest of the URI as another regex capture group and added that as a suffix to the alias

Comment: In that case, you should post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with the regular expression, but with the use of the `alias` directive within a regular expression `location`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for more.

On a related note, rather than using a negative lookahead assertion, you should use the `^~` modifier on the prefix `location`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

For example:

```
location ~ ^(/[^/]+)/api(.*)$ {
    alias /var/www/api$1$2;
}

location ^~ /api {
    alias /var/www/api/latest;
}
```

Comment: That's great, thank you! I had entirely misunderstood the fact that the regex locations were not prefixes.